# Scanning URL All the time - Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome

I need to develop extension, where everytime i write url and in chrome and press enter. My url is first scanned, if it matches some pattern say like if the url patter has youtube in it, redirect it to facebook

This should be done automatically - not everytime i have press the icon of (chrome extension), meaning this script or piece of code will not be running on-click event, rather once installed it will always scan the url entered and do the require change and reload the tab.

Please help me out. I reach this far

```
<html>
   <script>
  function getname()
  { 

  chrome.tabs.getSelected( null , function(tab) {   


        var rawurl="http://www.youtube.com/watch?";
        var newurl= "http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_leanback&"

           if (0 === tab.url.indexOf(rawurl)) 
          chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: tab.url.replace(rawurl,newurl)});    
  });
  }

  </script>
   <body onload="getname();">

  </body>
</html>
```

I achieve this but you onload event in J-Script - is there anyway I can do this all the time without using onload() as onload require explicit click all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting the code

```
   <html>
   <script>
  function getname()
  { 

  chrome.tabs.getSelected( null , function(tab) {   


        var rawurl="http://www.youtube.com/watch?";
        var newurl= "http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_leanback&"

           if (0 === tab.url.indexOf(rawurl)) 
          chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: tab.url.replace(rawurl,newurl)});    
  });
  }

  </script>
   <body onload="getname();">

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider APIs such like `chrome.webRequest` or `chrome.webNavigation`.

Besides, I believe [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lacckjdlmkdhcacjdodpjokfobckjclh) has implemented everything you mentioned.